# Openssl selfsigned certificate not trusted

Tags: ssl, certificate

I am developing a website which will need to have ssl so (just for my developing environment) I created ssl certificates for my test domain with openssl:

```
openssl req -x509 -new -out my.root.ca.crt -keyout my.root.ca.key -days 3650
openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -out my.domain.com.csr -pubkey -new -keyout my.domain.com.key
openssl x509 -req -in my.domain.com.csr -CA my.root.ca.crt -CAkey my.root.ca.key -CAcreateserial -out my.domain.com.crt -days 3650
```

And successfully applied it to apache with php.
The problem is that all browsers still see connection as not secure (not trusting the certificate) although I have added certificate to Trasted Root Authority on my developing PC. Chrome (ver 57) and IE (ver 11) not even giving an option to proceed.
When I check certificate in certmgr.msc, Certificate information says "the integrity of this certificate cannot be guaranteed" .
And I even rebooted my PC :)
Any ideas what I am doing wrong?
Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting Chrome to accept self-signed localhost certificate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7580508/getting-chrome-to-accept-self-signed-localhost-certificate)

Comment: rlandster -Thanks for the link
It helped me to sort the issue
Here what I used to create the certificate and after adding to trusted all works fine  
    openssl genrsa -des3 -out server.key 2048  
    openssl rsa -in server.key -out server.key  
    openssl req -sha256 -new -key server.key -out server.csr -subj   '/CN=localhost'

    openssl x509 -req -sha256 -days 365 -in server.csr -signkey server.key -out server.crt